# On error resume next type of error handling in PL/SQL oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Just like `On Error Resume Next` in VB coding ,is there a way to do same in `PL/SQL`

I have a sequence of select statments ,so when `no data found` exception thrown rather than having `begin exception` block is there a way to move to next statment

```
Eg

    select Name into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=1 and R='2';
    select Name into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=33 and R='3';
    select Name into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=11 and R='4';
    select Name into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=2 and R='5';
    select Name into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=4 and R='6';
```

so rather than

```
begin
select Name into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=1 and R='2';
exception
when no_data_found then
null
end;
```

is there a easy way to move to next statment

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no way to make PL/SQL act like VB in this regard. Best of luck.

Comment: I've researched too, and it seems the short answer is 'No.'  For those of us with classic VB experience, the Oracle solution is the VB equivalent of wrapping a statement you expect might fail inside of `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto ErrorHandler`.  That is, you would wrap the Oracle statement you expect might fail inside of `Begin` <Statement that might fail> `Exception` `When Others Then` `NULL;` `End;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you could use a local function:

```
declare
   l_name1 temp_tbl.name%type;
   function get_name
      ( p_t number
      , p_r varchar2
      ) return varchar2
   is
      l_name temp_tbl.name%type;
   begin
      select Name into l_name from TEMP_TBL where T=p_t and R=p_r;
      return l_name;
   exception    
      when no_data_found then
         return null;
   end;
begin
   l_name1 := get_name (1, '2');
   l_name1 := get_name (33, '3');
   l_name1 := get_name (11, '4');
   l_name1 := get_name (2, '5');
   l_name1 := get_name (4, '6');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your statement problem is trivialized in your example.  Tony's answer is what I would use, but alternatively, you can use aggregate functions:

```
select decode(count(*), 1, max(Name)) into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=1 and R='2';
select decode(count(*), 1, max(Name)) into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=33 and R='3';
select decode(count(*), 1, max(Name)) into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=11 and R='4';
select decode(count(*), 1, max(Name)) into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=2 and R='5';
select decode(count(*), 1, max(Name)) into l_name1 from TEMP_TBL where T=4 and R='6';
```

This approach will return null for any instances of (T,R) where there is not 1 and only 1 row.